# How to increase the size of rectangle in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I'm drawing something like a linked list, but my rectangles are pretty small, how can I increase their size?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal}, >=stealth, start chain]

  \node[list,on chain] (A) {1};
  \node[list,on chain] (B) {2};
  \node[list,on chain] (C) {2\nodepart{second} 3};

  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (A.two), \p2 = (A.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (B);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (B.two), \p2 = (B.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (C);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: for `rectangle split horizontal` you can only determine height of shape for whole shape. width can be determined only for each part separately as for example `\nodepart[minimum width=7mm]{second}`

Comment: @Zarko and how can I specify height?

Comment: `minimum height=...`, you should look in PGF & TikZ manual. I will prepare short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, chains, calc, positioning, shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 9mm and 12mm, % <vertical distance> and <horizontal distance> between nodes
  start chain = going right,
    mw/.style = {minimum width=#1},% for shortcut in "list" shapes
  list/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
                 rectangle split horizontal, draw,
                 align=center,
                 text width=7mm, % <-- have effect only on the foirst part of shape 
                 minimum height=9mm, % define height od multi part shape
                 inner sep=1mm, on chain}, 
          > = stealth, 
          ]

  \node[list] (A) {1\nodepart[mw=7mm]{two}  };
  \node[list] (B) {2\nodepart[mw=7mm]{two}  };
  \node[list] (C) {2\nodepart[mw=7mm]{two} 3};

  \node[list, below=of A] (D) {4\nodepart[mw=7mm]{two}  };% <-- observe correct syntax of "positioning" library
  \node[list] (E) {5\nodepart[mw=7mm]{two}  };
  \node[list] (F) {6\nodepart[mw=7mm]{two} 3};

  \draw[*->] ($(A.two north)!0.5!(A.two south)$) -- (B);
  \draw[*->] ($(B.two north)!0.5!(B.two south)$) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

of course, it is simpler just increase `inner sep` as suggest *AboAmmar* in his answer, but with his solution can width of shape parts wary. Anyway, see how the code of arrows are changed. Your approach is at least strange :).

**Edit:**
I expand above MWE with case of vertical for vertical align. Distance between nodes are determined with `node distance`.

I also change the numbers in shape part, that you can see, that the width of parts is independent of it content (when it is shorter then `text width, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But one more question, if I use something like this, and if I want to put some nodes below another one it gets shifted a bit to the right, is not exactly below. For example if we do `\node[list,below of=A] (B)...`. How can I make so that they are aligned when they are one below the other and the distance between them is visible, like in horizontal case?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

> [image]

When the rectangle is split horizontally, `minimum height` specifications will be effective, but any `minimum width` specifications will be ignored. And the `inner sep` will be applied to every part that is used. So, here I add `inner sep=1em`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, 
  rectangle split horizontal, inner sep=1em}, >=stealth, start chain]

  \node[list,on chain] (A) {1};
  \node[list,on chain] (B) {2};
  \node[list,on chain] (C) {2\nodepart{second} 3};

  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (A.two), \p2 = (A.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (B);
  \draw[*->] let \p1 = (B.two), \p2 = (B.center) in (\x1,\y2) -- (C);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's more like it. But the problem with using `below of` still persists. Please see below my comment to @Zarko's answer.

Comment: @typos : Please edit your question to add this extra requirement.