# How can I center the dot in the first part of box?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I center the dot in the first part of box? I want to make it look symmetrical. But don't know why the dot and arrow just won't center in the first part of box like the third part of box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   list/.style={minimum size=9mm,
   rectangle split,
   rectangle split parts=3,
   draw,
   rectangle split horizontal
},
   dotarrow/.style={Circle-Stealth},
   start chain
   ]
   \node[list,on chain] (A) {};
   \node[left of=A,xshift=-3mm] (1) {};
   \node[right of=A,xshift=3mm] (2) {};

   \draw[dotarrow] (A.three |- A.center) -- (2);
   \draw[dotarrow] (A.one |- A.center) -- (1);

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is not compilable. It brings many errors. Please make it compilable. Starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Well, this piece of code should be able to display in any document type....What do you mean by not compilable??

Comment: You are missing all the necessary libraries. But the answer is that the circle arrow head is put next to the point not on the point. So it is a visual problem.

Comment: To be honest, I pulled this off from a document that a group of people are working on......I'm in the group of course......There are at least 500 lines of preamble, and at least 1000 pages of codes already......You ask me which library is for this?? My guess is just tikz.....let me try to find out ....

Comment: @Cragfelt Ok....I just edit the code, now should be ok......could you please help me now???

Comment: @percusse Well, I need a fix, all right? I can see the problem, but I don't know how to fix it....

Comment: In https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401764/tikz-line-dots-and-trees/401771#401771 you can find one possible definition of a new arrow tip (called `Midcircle`) where the circle is centered on the end coordinate of the line.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360916/how-to-increase-the-size-of-rectangle-in-tikz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two problems. One is that as Percusse points out, the circle at the beginning of the `dotarrow` doesn't go exactly at the coordinate given. The second problem is that the `A.one` and `A.three` anchors appear to be in slightly odd locations. The easy solution to the first problem is to put a node with shape a filled circle at the end of your arrow. A harder solution would be to make a modified version of the `dot` arrowhead with no offset. It seems like the easy solution is sufficient here.

To solve the second problem, it appears that the anchor `A.one south` is located at the center of the bottom edge of the region. So to get the two edges say:

```
\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill, inner sep=1.3pt}}
\draw (A.three south |- A.center) node[dot]{} -- (2);
\draw (A.one south |- A.center) node[dot]{} -- (1);
```

The complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   list/.style={minimum size=9mm,
   rectangle split,
   rectangle split parts=3,
   draw,
   rectangle split horizontal
},
   dot/.style={circle,fill, inner sep=1.3pt},
   -Stealth,
   start chain
   ]
   \node[list,on chain] (A) {};
   \node[left of=A,xshift=-3mm] (1) {};
   \node[right of=A,xshift=3mm] (2) {};

   \draw (A.three south |- A.center) node[dot]{} -- (2);
   \draw (A.one south |- A.center) node[dot]{} -- (1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```